# serverless lambda@edge s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I`m trying to upload lambda@edge with serverless but its not working, I cant see logs on the cloudwatch.

```
service: image-compress

frameworkVersion: '2'
plugins:
  - serverless-bundle

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  memorySize: 128
  lambdaHashingVersion: '20201221'
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'staging'}
  environment:
    ENV: ${self:provider.stage}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:*"
      Resource:
        - "arn:aws:s3:::*"

functions:
  image-reduce:
    handler: handler.reducer
    events:
      - cloudFront:
          eventType: origin-response
          origin: s3://cropped-images-test2.s3.amazonaws.com/
          isDefaultOrigin: true

custom:
  bundle:
    linting: false
    packagerOptions:
      scripts:
        - npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux sharp
```

This is the serverless yml, I can see this configuration on the cloudFront but I cant seem to get any logs when trying to receive images.

any help?